# MySql how to combine LEFT JOIN query with NOT IN query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, notin

I need to combine `LEFT JOIN` query with `NOT IN` query and have to get the result values from these queries. I have get the correct results while using these two queries at separately.

I have two tables likely `user` and `answer`

`user` table

```
user_id 
1
2
3
4
5
```

`answer` table

```
user_id     date 
1           2015-10-15 21:23:14
2           2015-10-15 20:23:14
3           2015-11-11 16:23:14
```

`LEFT JOIN` query:

```
SELECT user.user_id
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN answer 
  ON user.user_id = answer.user_id 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),answer.date) > 5
```

This query returns result `user_id` 1,2.

`NOT IN` query:

```
SELECT user.user_id 
FROM user 
WHERE user.user_id NOT IN (SELECT answer.user_id FROM answer)
```

This query returns result `user_ids` 4, 5.

I need to combine this two queries into single query so I tried with these two below queries:

```
 SELECT user.user_id 
 FROM user 
 LEFT JOIN answer 
   ON user.user_id = answer.user_id 
 WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(),answer.date) > 5 
   AND user.user_id NOT IN (SELECT answer.user_id FROM answer))
```

and

```
 SELECT user.user_id 
 FROM user 
 LEFT JOIN answer 
   ON user.user_id = answer.user_id 
 WHERE user.user_id NOT IN (SELECT answer.user_id FROM answer) 
   AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),answer.date) > 5
```

But these return empty `user_id`.

**Edit**

Expected result should contain values of `1,2,4,5`

Comment: What do you expect to see as output?

Comment: shouldn't that be `WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),answer.date) < 5` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your meaning is about to combine 2 selection together 
 Try **Union All** / **Union** :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT [WITH YOUR LEFT JOIN STATEMENT]
UNION 
SELECT [WITH YOUR NOT IN STATEMENT]
) ResultTABLE
```

Comment: This is how we emulated `LEFT JOINS` in the past, before SQL92 introduced them.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the answer table in the `WHERE` clause, the `answer.date` will be restricted to non-NULL value, making the `LEFT JOIN` behave like a regular join. Move the condition to the `ON` condition to retrieve *all* the users, plus *maybe* the matching rows in `answers`:

```
 SELECT user.user_id
 FROM user u
 LEFT JOIN answer a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
                    AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),a.date) < 5
    ;
```

---

Edit: after the edit of the question it appears the OP wants joined records with non existing answer OR answer.date too old/young:

```
 SELECT user.user_id
 FROM user u
 LEFT JOIN answer a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
 WHERE a.date IS NULL               -- no answer record
    OR DATEDIFF(NOW(),a.date) > 5   -- too old answer record
    ;
```

---

Final version: Since the OP wants to find users who don't have a (recent) answer, the query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT user.user_id
FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM answer a
    WHERE a.user_id = u.user_id
    AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.date) <= 5
    );
```

Comment: I.e. with the answer table's condition in the WHERE clause like that, the LEFT JOIN executes as a regular INNER JOIN.

Comment: Exactly! (I'll add that)

Comment: @joop your edited answer returns `1,2,4,5` but I need `3,4,5`

Comment: sorry actually my `left join`  query returning values of `1,2` but I thought that `3` alone.

Comment: That is because the `greater than` sign is flipped (see my comment on the question) I'll fix it for you.